# Is it possible to use Jasper Reports to generate reports from LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, jasper-reports

I'd like to be able to include the results of LDAP queries in Jasper reports.  Is that feasible?  From what I can gather it seems that the only way to go about this is to write my own custom datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can/could.

Basically you would have to write your own datasource to query LDAP based on the query provided by the report/sub-dataset.

Alternatively, though I've never used them, you could try a [JDBC-LDAP bridge](http://www.openldap.org/jdbcldap/). If your query needs are fairly straightforward,this may be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible.... We can connect to any datasource (DB or custom datasource) and we can execute any SQL query or even we can configure map to act as a datasource to execute report from java application....